# continuous fadein for an image shows two images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, slideshow

I am making a image tour(slideshow).  so I am hiding all the images and appending the last images to image container or prepending based on whether it's previous or next.

```
$('.img-container').find('img:first').fadeIn('300');  


<div class="img-container">
  <img src="/assets/v2/explore.png">
  <img src="/assets/v2/Analyze.png">
</div>
```

I use the above code to show the image. but when I do this continuously at one time there are two images in the same slide. How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you should show us some more code - in your above code there is nothing wrong. Where do you handle the append and prepend?

Comment: try to put your code in fiddle...

Comment: @FabianLurz ya i think the problem is with fadein('') because when i replace it with hide it works perfectly.

Comment: You should then maybe try fadeOut ;)